# Regex: Only numbers, letters, or space, but not only numbers

Tags: regex

I have this text

```
ford fiesta 2010,60500,2.54
ford fiesta review,5400,1.81
ford,5400,1.81
```

I want to get

```
ford fiesta 2010
ford fiesta review
ford
```

I use this regex

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ])+[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

But it can't match `ford` since it doesn't have any spaces.
Any suggestions?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Why not simply all that is before the comma ? And what regex flavor/language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to match optional following words, separated by spaces would be

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[ ]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33eer).

`^` matches the start of the string

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches then the first word

`(?:[ ]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` matches optional words separated by one or more leading commas.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, you can do it with:

```
$input = 'ford fiesta 2010,60500,2.54';
list($output) = explode(',', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case no need to `regex`, try `String.Split` (C#)

```
var result = inputString.Split(new[]{','})[0];
```

or use this regex:

```
^([^,]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex with `multiline` option

```
^\w+(?=,)
```